# Image Pressed In Effect -- CSS

Tags: html, css, photoshop

I was wondering how to achieve the following effect (Mozilla Start Page) where the icons look "pressed into" the page.  Is that something that can be accomplished with CSS or is this purely a photoshop maneuver and and the background-color is just matched?

[image]

Comment: How are you currently displaying the icons? Transparent or non-transparent images? SVG, icon font?...

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick, feel free to play around with the colour as  you see fit:

```
div {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 #C7C7C7 inset;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E9E9E9;
}
```

Comment: Possible to provide an example? I'm not sure how this is going to work for those icons, assuming they are images.

Comment: I would suggest he use an icon library `i` and apply the style to the icon, rather than using images. Those sprites are quite common icons

Comment: If he is using an icon font then he can do it with `text-shadow` rather than `box-shadow`

Comment: @mlegg thats not the desired look that Theodore has asked for